# Displaying total progress bar when spliting array in portions with multiprocesssing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tqdm

I have a code where I am computing the average of an array whislt displaying a progress bar.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mtp

def split_list(some_list, size):
  for i in range(0, len(some_list), size):
      yield some_list[i:i + size]  


def foo(x):
    return np.square(x)

def main():
    a = np.arange(1000)
    av = 0
    with mtp.Pool(4) as pool:
        for l in split_list(a, 33):
            output = list(tqdm(pool.imap(foo, l), total = len(a)))
            av += np.sum(output)
        av /= len(a)
        
    return av
```

This is showing several progress bars. I would like to only have one with the overall progress.

How can I do this?

EDIT:

I have something that sudo-works

```
def main():
    a = [np.random.rand(10, 3, 3) for _ in range(1000)]
    av = 0
    
    with mtp.Pool(4) as pool:
      with tqdm.tqdm(total = len(a)) as p_bar:
        for l in split_list(a, 33):
            output = list(pool.imap(foo, l))
            av += np.sum(output)
            p_bar.update(len(l))

    av /= len(a)
    return av
```

But it will only update in chuncks not as the results are available.

Answer (score 2):

Your `split_list` function is creating some number of sub-lists whose length is 33 (except for possibly the last sub-list). So as each sub-list is processed you need to advance the progress bar by the length of the sub-list just processed and you need to process *all* the sub-lists as *one* call to `imap_unordered` (which is faster than `imap` and for computing the average of the squares you don't care what order the results are returned):

```py
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mtp

def split_list(some_list, size):
  for i in range(0, len(some_list), size):
      yield some_list[i:i + size]


def foo(x):
    return np.square(x)

def main():
    a = np.arange(1000)
    the_sum = 0
    with mtp.Pool(4) as pool, tqdm(total=len(a)) as pbar:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(foo, split_list(a, 33)):
            the_sum += np.sum(result)
            pbar.update(len(result))
    av = the_sum / len(a)

    return av

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

Prints:

```None
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1000/1000 [00:00<00:00, 3546.10it/s]
332833.5
```

**Update**

As long as you are creating chunks yourself and returning the squares of each element of the chunk using `np.square`, I don't see how you can avoid updating the progress bar in chunks. If you want a progress bar of size 1000 to be updated one bar at a time, you have to perform 1000 actions:

```py
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mtp

def foo(x):
    return x ** 2

def main():
    a = np.arange(1000)
    the_sum = 0
    with mtp.Pool(4) as pool, tqdm(total=len(a)) as pbar:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(foo, a):
            the_sum += result
            pbar.update()
    av = the_sum / len(a)

    return av

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

**Note**

As I have indicated in comments, the only way I see to increment a progress bar of size N is to perform N operations and to update the progress bar at the completion of each operation. There are several ways of doing this (and I showed you one above), but essentially they all require replacing `np.square`, which was squaring 33 integers at a time with an explicit loop that squares individually each of the 33 integers.

If you want another way that allows you to pass to `foo` a sub-list of size 33 and still update the progress bar every time you square an element of the sub-list, then the following code would be one way. It consists of communicating back to the main process an "event" that signifies that a squaring operation has completed. Below we use a `multiprocessing.Queue`. `foo` puts some arbitrary item to the queue when it completes a squaring operation and the main process fetches these "events" from the queue and updates the progress bar.

Here we update the size of `a` to have 1,000,000 elements:

```py
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mtp

def split_list(some_list, size):
  for i in range(0, len(some_list), size):
      yield some_list[i:i + size]

def pool_initializer(the_queue):
    global q

    q = the_queue


def foo(x):
    partial_sum = 0
    for elem in x:
        # convert np.int64 to int and then square it
        partial_sum += int(elem) ** 2
        q.put(None) # Value is not important
    return partial_sum

def main():
    a = np.arange(1_000_000, dtype=np.int64)
    the_sum = 0

    q = mtp.Queue()
    with mtp.Pool(4, initializer=pool_initializer, initargs=(q,)) as pool, \
    tqdm(total=len(a)) as pbar:
        it = pool.imap_unordered(foo, split_list(a, 33))
        for _ in range(len(a)):
            q.get()
            pbar.update()
        the_sum = sum(it)

    av = the_sum / len(a)
    return av

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

Prints:

```
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1000000/1000000 [00:32<00:00, 31107.52it/s]
333332833333.5
```

Versus the way I suggested doing this (with suitable modifications) was to report by chunks:

```py
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mtp

def split_list(some_list, size):
  for i in range(0, len(some_list), size):
      yield some_list[i:i + size]


def foo(x):
    return np.square(x, dtype=np.int64)

def main():
    a = np.arange(1_000_000, dtype=np.int64)
    the_sum = 0
    with mtp.Pool(4) as pool, tqdm(total=len(a)) as pbar:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(foo, split_list(a, 33)):
            the_sum += int(np.sum(result, dtype=np.int64))
            pbar.update(len(result))
    av = the_sum / len(a)

    return av

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

Prints:

```
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1000000/1000000 [00:09<00:00, 109517.22it/s]
333332833333.5
```

**The runs were respectively 32 seconds and 9 seconds. Reporting chunks is almost 4 times faster. The larger the chunks you use the better the performance will be. If I increase the array size to 50,000,000 (from 1,000,000) but increase the chunk size to 10,000 (from 33), then the running time actually reduces from 9 seconds to 2 seconds (`tqdm` is only reporting time that is rounded to the nearest second).**

Comment: This code is updating the bar in chunks.  I would like to update the bar as the results are made available within the chunks. Let us say that you have an extramely big array with 1e6 points. You create chunks of 1e4 portions. You will only get updates of 1e4 portions. I would like to have it available as they are being calculated. As you have when you dont have chunks

Comment: You are creating the chunks yourself and calling `np.square` that sums 33 squares at a time with that one single operation. If you sent your progress bar to size 1000, how can you possibly in any meaningful way advance it one bar at a time since there is no code that sums anything one item at a time. **The only alternative is to not split your 1000 elements and to pass to `foo` one element at a time and to have it return the square of that single number.  You will then be calling `foo` 1000 times and doing 1000 additions.** See the updated answer.

Comment: The ideia for chunking is because I have an array that will not fit in memory, so I have to partion it into chunk. But If the chunks are too big I will not to be see the progress for quite some time. If I cannot fix the way the chunked approach is reporting values with tqdm I will have to live with it. Thanks for the support!

Comment: I added a **Note** that includes another way of advancing the progress bar after each squaring operation with timings that should further convince you not do it that way but to rather advance the progress bar when processing a chunk completes. And for this problem you want the largest possible chunk size memory will allow for best performance. **Updating a progress bar should be secondary to efficiency.**

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simply the place you have placed the "tqdm" class. Each time the loop "for l in split_list(a, 33)" enters a new value, a new progress bar is generated.

It also can happen that if the "multiprocessing" module function you are using prints messages, either through "print" or "LOG", this messages will interrupt the progress bar, and a new bar will be generated under the message with the progress of the previous bars accumulated.

If you only want one single progress bar, you should place it in the "for" loop statement and check for printed messages.

IMPORTANT: I have never worked with multiprocessing, I'm just talking about the "tqdm" module.

Comment: I was able to make in one progresss bar. But it will update in chunks, not as results are available